# SDL2: Is there a way to prevent a resizeable window from attempting to become fullscreen when dragged to the top of the screen?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I have a resizable window in SDL2, and when I drag the window to the top of the screen it becomes fullscreen. This is a problem for me because I don't want it to be a full screen (I'm expanding the window at a fixed ratio so that the textures don't become skewed).

**TL;DR: Is there a way to prevent the resizeable window from attempting to become fullscreen when dragged to the top of the screen?**

> [image: Window beubg expabded]
>
> See the gray box that previews the window expansion

Comment: I think it's the window manager that does this, not the application. So my guess is that it's not possible. I may be wrong though.

Comment: "I'm expanding the window at a fixed ratio so that the textures don't become skewed"  Instead of trying to override the user's chosen window-management behavior why not letter-box inside your program?

Comment: @genpfault What's letter-boxing?

Comment: [Adding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)) black bars to the sides/top of an image so you can aspect-scale within a given bounding-box.

Comment: @genpfault thank you 